# Why is vlc screen stopped showing

Tags: vlc-media-player

[image]

I can't see the vlc screen anymore.I dont know what happened suddenly.
I can hear audio and probably video is also playing but i can't see the vlc screen.As seen in the screen shot its just visible in the taskbar and doesn't show up even if i click it there.

Tried uninstalling and installing but same result.

Comment: Do you use more than one monitor? If you changed setup, it could be hidden.

Comment: only one monitor  connected with cable. i don't know if any settings got changed ..still trying to figure it out

Comment: Try to reset VLC defaults. Look for something like this: `Start Menu > Programs > VLC > Reset VLC media player preferences and cache files`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reset VLC defaults.

```
Start Menu > Programs > VLC > Reset VLC media player preferences and cache files
```